React Native with Tailwind CSS
How can we setup for react-native project on windows using CLI(I don't want to create any EXPO project)and how can we integrate it with Tailwind CSS without any error?
Also can a NPM can be converted into a YARN in this project?
I want to setup a project that can run on both android as well as ios, it helps me a lot

Using Tailwind CSS classes in React Native is made possible by NativeWind, which may streamline and expedite the styling process. A low-level tool for building designs is offered by Tailwind CSS, a utility-first CSS framework. It comes with a wide range of pre-made utility classes that can help you style your project more quickly and consistently.

Set Up Your Environment : https://reactnative.dev/docs/set-up-your-environment

React Native Environment Setup in Windows (10,11) 2024|How to install react native in windows : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4onhZMbF2NI

React-native CLI -> In this video, he guide you through the process of integrating Tailwind CSS into your React Native CLI app :- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iTALto31-Gs

React Native Expo How to Add Tailwind CSS to Your React Native Expo App : https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/tailwindcss-in-react-native-expo/


